# How to set list A equal to list B, where on B a property does not exist which does exist on A

Tags: c#, json, list, serialization

I have a C# list which is of type Person. This list needs to be converted into JSON data format. The Person C# class look like this:

```
 public class Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public static int PSID = 1;
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string nameToken { get; set; }
        public double DOB { get; set; }
        public List<Award> awards { get; set;  }
        public List<Link> links { get; set; }

        public Person()
        {

            awards = new List<Award>();
            links = new List<Link>();
            ID = PSID;
            PSID++;
        }


    }
```

As I am required to convert a C# list of type Person into JSON. I made another Class in C# called PersonJS. It is exactly like the Person C# class the only difference is that I have removed some of the properties that are not required in the JSON front-end. Namely: nameToken, PSID.

```
public class PersonJS
{

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public double DOB { get; set; }

    public List<AwardJS> awards { get; set; }

    public List<Link> links { get; set; }


}
```

One of the properties of PersonJS is a List called awards which is of Type AwardJS. A problem occurs below because I try and equal Person.awards List equal to PersonJS.awards List. However, they are of difference types so it is not possible to equal both lists. The reason why I have put them equal to different types is because the JSON data does not need all of the properties that I have used in C#. So I made two classes Award and AwardJS. The only difference is that Award contains a property called filmWebToken whereas AwardJS does not.

```
public class Award
  {

    public int filmID { get; set; }

    public int categoryID { get; set; }

    public string filmWebToken { get; set; }
}



public class AwardJS
{

    public int filmID { get; set; }

    public int categoryID { get; set; }

}
```

In my code I iterate over all of the properties in C# list of type **Person** and I attempt to create a personjs object and add it to a **PersonJS** C# list. The **PersonJS** list will go back to the front-end as JSON. However, because the award property in the class PersonJS is different to the award property in Person I get the error **"Cannot implicitly convert type AwardJS to Award"**. The reason I get this error is because PersonJS does not contain **filmWebToken** which exists in the Person class. I don't want the filmWebToken to be in the PersonJS list as it is not meant to be a property in my JSON data. However, as there are property fields in Person.Award I still want access to: filmID and CategoryID how can I ignore/by-pass the filmWebToken field. This is what I have tried:

```
 List<Person> allPersons = DataRepository.GetAllPersons(); // contains the C# data 
        List<PersonJS> personjs = new List<PersonJS>(); // empty to start with

        foreach (var person in allPersons)
        {
            foreach (var award in person.awards) 
            {
                personjs.Add(
                    new PersonJS
                    {
                        ID = person.ID,
                        links = person.links, 
                        name = person.name,
                        DOB = person.DOB,
                        awards = person.awards // The types are not equal: Person contains filmWebToken whereas PersonJS does not


                    });



            }


        }
```

Comment: Looks like you just need to project the relevant parts of your `Award` type into a new `AwardJS` isntance, very similarly to how you are projecting each `Person` into a new `PersonJS`. LINQ has a nice way to tackle this with the `Select` method for projecting values.

Comment: Automapper is pretty good for this sort of thing. http://automapper.org/

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth could you give an example please

Comment: @hoChay Sweeper's answer shows one way of doing it.

Comment: @AdmHouldsworth Thanks, I get the error "the name awardjs does not exist in current context"  when I added ToAwardJs into the Award class. If I write:                                                                                                   AwardJs awardjs =  new AwardJS() { filmID = this.filmID, categoryID = this.categoryID }; return awardjs, will that suffice

Comment: Also, you can just mark properties not supposed to be serialized with [JsonIgnore] attribute.

Comment: @hoChay see my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

Add a method called `ToAwardJS` in `Award`:

```
public AwardJS ToAwardJS() {
    return new AwardJS { filmID = this.filmID, categoryID = this.categoryID };
}
```

Then when you create the `PersonJS` object, do:

```
new PersonJS
{
    ID = person.ID,
    links = person.links, 
    name = person.name,
    DOB = person.DOB,
    awards = person.awards.Select(x => x.ToAwardJS()).ToList(),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What serializer are you using?  Most provide attributes to specify which members to include in the serialization.  For example, the DataContractJsonSerializer uses `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]`.  I think Json.net uses `[JsonIgnore]`.  There's no need for multiple classes.

```
void Main()
{
    var jsSer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Person));

    var p = new Person {
        ID = 1,
        name = "John",
        DOB = 1234.5,
        nameToken = "token"
    };

    string result = null;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        jsSer.WriteObject(ms, p);
        byte[] json = ms.ToArray();
        ms.Close();

        result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(json, 0, json.Length);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    //included
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string nameToken { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double DOB { get; set; }

    //ignored
    public static int PSID = 1;
    public List<string> awards { get; set;  }
    public List<string> links { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {

        awards = new List<Award>();
        links = new List<Link>();
        ID = PSID;
        PSID++;
    }
}
```

Result:

> {"DOB":1234.5,"ID":1,"name":"John","nameToken":"token"}